# Facebook sharing image (og:image) not working the first time despite having og:image:width and og:image:height

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

I'm building an image on the fly to attach to page to be shared on facebook. Everything seems to be going great until it hits the share dialog. Facebook doesn't seem to be scraping, because the image isn't showing up. If I refresh that dialog page, it does load the image (having crawled it from the first go?).

I've read several pages that say I need only specify *og:image:width* and *og:image:height* to allow for immediate rendering, but that doesn’t seem to be working. Here are my meta tags:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="###"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="###" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Page Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My Page Description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://the-domain/the-image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: im having the same problem and cannot work it out. height and width are being provided but facebook doesn't show it as part of the preview.

Comment: Same problem, it seems than the only solution is go to sharer debugger ant scrape the url until it works :(        Any advances?

Comment: Maybe a solution can be to automatize something like a redirection in an iframe the facebook sharing debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http://myweb.com/path

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of issues, I recommend checking out the debugging tool that Facebook provides. It's great for quick identification of show stopping errors like you're receiving.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Just a couple of things to keep in mind, sometimes the image or page will time out if Facebook finds that it's taking longer than 1s to fetch the data. I've also found issues with my own implementations if the og:url is different than the page you're expecting Facebook to fetch. The two values must match, because ultimately it's the og:url value that facebook is trying to scrape.

Comment: Yup, the page is coming up completely clean in the debug tool. Also, the og:url appears to be identical to the share page url, no redirects or https funny business. Appreciate the ideas tho.

Comment: Does the image appear in the debugging tools?

Comment: @biscuitcleaver the facebook debug tool gives me this issue  could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb or your server was too slow to respond.
i am getting images from cloud front  and images are less than 30 kb and also they are valid image urls to if i give the url in browser then the images are being shows but facebook debug tool gives me this error.
Kindly help me on this issue please.

Comment: What resolution are your images?